# Install fusehq-agent with fabric8?

Tags: fabric8

Is the fusehq-agent mentioned in the fabric8 docs the same as JBoss Operations Network agent?

[fabric8 Process Manager](http://fabric8.io/#/site/book/doc/index.md?chapter=processManager_md)

```
process:install -k fusehq-agent someURLToDistro
```

I see this link on the redhat site which leads me to think that fusehq-agent means the new JON agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes FuseHQ was the name of the Fuse plugin for FuseHQ, which was the product names from FuseSource. Later FuseSource was acquired by Red Hat, and the Red Hat offers the JON instead of FuseHQ.

The fabric documentation and the source code in fabric8 should be updated to refer to JON instead. I have logged a ticket: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/issues/1142